# Storing csv data in dictionary

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, dictionary

I am using python 3. I have sample data in a csv file, which i would like to convert to a dictionary:

Data in a.csv:

```
a.fruit,a.colour,a.quantity 
apple,red,2 
grapes,purple,4
pear,green,5
```

I have the following code:

```
sample = 'samples.csv'
file_name = open(sample,'r')

reader = csv.DictReader(file_name)
for row in reader:
    print(row)
```

When i run the code, i get the following output:

```
['a.fruit':'apple','a.colour':'red','a.quantity':'2']
['a.fruit':'grapes','a.colour':'purple','a.quantity':'4']
['a.fruit':'pear','a.colour':'green','a.quantity':'5']
```

Is there anyway for me to get the following dictionary:

```
[{'a.fruit':['apple','grapes','pear'],'a.colour':['red','purple','green'],'a.quantity':['2','4','5'}]
```

so a dict representation stored in (str: list of str) for (key:value)?

Also, is it possible to the following output: 
 [a : {'a.fruit':['apple','grapes','pear'],'a.colour':['red','purple','green'],'a.quantity':['2','4','5'}]

Comment: Please post the actual output you got.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [list comprehension](http://www.diveinto.org/python3/comprehensions.html#listcomprehension) and [dict comprehension](http://www.diveinto.org/python3/comprehensions.html#dictionarycomprehension) like this

```
dicts = [row for row in reader]
result = {k:[d[k] for d in dicts] for k in dicts[0].keys()}
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
{'a.fruit': ['apple', 'grapes', 'pear'], 'a.colour': ['red', 'purple', 'green'], 'a.quantity ': ['2 ', '4', '5']}
```

Comment: @user3044013 What is the contents of the file?